# bitstamp live trades in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, api, codeigniter

I am new to bitstamp API and I want to do this type like
[image]

and i am using php pusher library https://github.com/antonigiske/Pusher-CI/blob/master/readme.md but i don't know why i am getting a

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PusherException**

My HTML Code are

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="" style="width: 40%;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Time Since</th>
            <th >Amount</th>
            <th >Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="showDataHere">

            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

And I want to update my table every 5seconds. So I do this

```
<script>
   function callMe()
    {
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo base_url();?>home/live_tradess",
               success: function(response){
                          $("#showDataHere").html(response);
                        }
       });
    }

// Call it 
// "setInterval" means every 5 secs 
// "setTimeout" just once...

setInterval(callMe, 5000); </script>
```

My PHP code are this

```
public function live_tradess()
{
    if(!class_exists('Pusher'))
        $this->load->library('Pusher');
    $this->Pusher->trigger('live_trades', 'event', array('message' => 'Hello World'));
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error states that a class is declared twice. You can find `PusherException` keyword on project level and can find where is second declaration. It might be due to unfinished installation.